# What is the VPC accepted address and why

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, subnet, amazon-vpc, cidr

i am trying to create a vpc but the ip i am providing is not accepted which is 192.168.1.1/16 but aws says i can use the following range if i set to 192.168.0.0/16 it works , i guess to an extent still some clarity would be great

```
When you create a VPC, we recommend that you specify a CIDR block (of /16 or smaller) from the private IPv4 address ranges as specified in RFC 1918:

10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (10/8 prefix)

172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (172.16/12 prefix)

192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

Comment: 192.168.1.1/16 is not valid network definition as 192.168.1.1 falls inside the 192.168.0.0/16 range - usually it is unlikely that you need 256*256 IP-addresses in a single VPC and you'd use something like `192.168.1.0/24` to be able to use the ip-addresses  `192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.255`

Comment: so if i want 16834 host it would be something like this right 192.0.0.0./14 am i right ?

Comment: If you want to use 16834 hosts that is a `/18` , not a  `/14`.  There are 4 `/18` subnets in 192.168/16 that you could use:  `192.168.0.0/18`  `192.168.64.0/18` `192.168.128.0/18` and `192.168.196.0/18` . A  `/14` on the other hand  (with max 262142 hosts) ` can only be created as a subset from the 10.0.0.0/8 or 172.16/12 
 ranges as the IP-addresses `192.0.0.0 - 192.167.255.255`  are not reserved for  private use but allocated in the real world. But us a subnet calculator to learn more

Comment: sorry made a mistake thanks :)  i counted the 1s instead of 0s for the host please let me know if below two examples are correct !


4194304 Host  - 192.0.0.0/10
32 Host - 192.168.1.0/27

Comment: Use one of the many online subnet / cidr calculators that will do the job for you much more quickly than I can explain - Look at https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work and https://serverfault.com/q/630022/37681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my ip was not accepted in the VPC is because 192.168.1.1 is considered as single ip which is taken as 192.168.1.1/32 it is invalid as VPC CIDR needs a range of ip address like these two example.

```
192.168.0.0/16 
192.168.1.0/27
```

Comment: Yeah CIDR addresses for the common sizes (/8, /16, /32) have the last quartet of the IP address 0 (eg x.x.x.0). When you get to other sizes like /27 networks they can start at other numbers - eg x.x.x.32/28.

Comment: yes tim i did not realize until others pointed thanks :)

Comment: I didn't read the comments, I just wanted to add a little more right beside the answer that you will accept in 24 hours :)

Comment: haha... any input is welcome as i am a novice